# Scroll StackPannel Horizontally with ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I have a problem that I can't solve. I need to scroll a `StackPannel` Horizontally with a `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid`. This works but is incorrect gesture, to scroll forward I need to diagonally swipe down and back diagonally up. I need this to work normally swipe left and right.

```
<Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
<ScrollViewer Height="130" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,70,-3"  >
<StackPanel Height="73" Margin="0,0,0,50" Width="30956" Orientation="Horizontal"  >

<!-- Here i have a lot of buttons -->

</StackPannel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I've tried to play with `ScrollViewer.Horizontal` and `VerticalBarVisibility` for `StackPannel` and Grid but with no succes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the horizontalScrollBarvisibility on the scrollviewer. I.e

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Height="130" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,70,-3"  >
        <StackPanel Height="73" Margin="0,0,0,50" Width="30956" Orientation="Horizontal"  >


        </StackPannel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant you need to remove the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility on the Grid.

Comment: Did this fix your problem in the end?